# Ошибка при попытке free(<димнамический массив>);

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Всем доброго времени суток! У написал программу, в конце при очистке free(symbols); выходит какая-то ошибка, подскажите в чем проблема и по возможности как ее решить! Заранее спасибо!

[image: Ошибка]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#define fflush while (getchar() != '\n')
#define BOARD printf("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n\n")

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    do
    {
        system("cls");

        int *numbers, *isControlIn, AmountOfNumbers, AmountOfSymbols;
        char *symbols;


//Ввод данных для целочисленного массива

        isControlIn = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

        do
        {
            printf("Введите количество элементов целочисленного массива массива (n >= 2): ");
            *isControlIn = scanf("%d", &AmountOfNumbers) - 1;
            fflush;

            if ((*isControlIn) || (AmountOfNumbers < 2))
            {
                printf("Вы ввели неверные данные, попробуйте еще раз!\n");
                *isControlIn = 1;
            }

        } while (*isControlIn);

        free(isControlIn);

        BOARD;

//Ввод целочисленного массива

        printf("Введите целочисленный массив из %d элементов: ", AmountOfNumbers);

        numbers = (int*)calloc(AmountOfNumbers, sizeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfNumbers; i++)
            if (!scanf("%d", numbers + i)) getchar();
        fflush;

        BOARD;

// Ввод данных для символьного массива

        do
        {
            printf("Введите количество элементов символьного массива (n >= 2): ");
            *isControlIn = scanf("%d", &AmountOfSymbols) - 1;
            fflush;

            if ((*isControlIn) || (AmountOfSymbols < 2))
            {
                printf("Вы ввели неверные данные, попробуйте еще раз!\n");
                *isControlIn = 1;
            }

        } while (*isControlIn);

        BOARD;

//Ввод символьного массива

        printf("Введите символьный массив из %d элементов СЛИТНО!: ", AmountOfSymbols);

        symbols = (char*)calloc(AmountOfSymbols, sizeof(char));
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfSymbols; i++)
            scanf("%c", symbols + i);
        BOARD;

// Промежуточный вывод символьного и целочисленного массива

        printf("Промежуточный вывод введенных массивов: \n");

        printf("Целочисленный массив:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfNumbers; i++)
            printf("%3d | (%p)\n", *(numbers + i), numbers + i);

        printf("Символьный массив:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfSymbols; i++)
            printf("  %c | (%p)\n", *(symbols + i), symbols + i);

        BOARD;

//Работа с массивами
//Нахождение суммы положительных элементов в целочисленном массиве

        int *s;
        s = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *s = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfSymbols; i++)
            if (*(numbers + i) >= 0) *s += *(numbers + i);

        free(numbers);

//Вывод значения суммы положительных элементов уелочисленного массива

        printf("Сумма всех положительных элементов целочисленного массива S = %d (%p)\n", *s, s);
        free(s);

//Циклическая перестановка символьного массива

        char *buffer;
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

        *buffer = *(symbols + AmountOfSymbols - 1);

        for (int i = AmountOfSymbols; i > 0; i--)
            *(symbols + i) = *(symbols + i - 1);

        *symbols = *buffer;

//Вывод символьного массива

        printf("Символьный массив:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfSymbols; i++)
            printf("  %c | (%p)\n", *(symbols + i), symbols + i);
        BOARD;

        free(buffer);
        free(symbols);  //Вот тут почему то ругается

        printf("Нажмите ESC чтобы закончить работу, иначе нажмите любую другую клadишу!\n");
    }while (_getch() != 27);
}
```

Comment: Явное повреждение памяти при записи где-то...

Comment: Вот интересно, в чем глубокий философский смысл создания таких переменных? Да еще и в цикле..         `buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));`  Неужели обычной автоматической не хватает? Ну или глобальной.. Это же просто пустая трата машинного времени (в данном коде). Конечно, это не ошибка, но код был бы проще.

Comment: Кстати, если собрать программу в GCC, то никаких ошибок пока не нашел. Подозреваю, что это может крыша ехать у VS при циклическом выделении/удалении динамических переменных (в древней VS 6 от 1996 года я с таким встречался). А еще, Вы пометили вопрос как Си, но используете С++ (#include <iostream>)

Comment: А что такое *fflush;*? Что это значит?

Comment: Что такое `#include <iostream>`???

Comment: "Циклическая перестановка символьного массива" реализована неправильно. Цикл должен начинаться с `AmountOfSymbols - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
symbols = (char*)calloc(AmountOfSymbols + 1, sizeof(char));
```